Fixed Camera Resolution in Rendered Preview Mode
I was wondering if does anyone knows about some addon or script that would allow you to have a fixed camera resolution in a Rendered Preview Mode.
So basically same thing as an "Always use camera resolution" option in Blender with Octane or just same as in Corona or VRay with 3Ds Max.
To explain better - the resolution of the image you see in Viewport is always the same as it is set in output setting, regarding of the zoom level or windows size, so if you were to zoom in on some small object in the frame, you would see it pixelated because that's how it would look like if you would zoom in on a final rendered image.
I have tried to write some script with help of ChatGPT but with no success. In my head it sounds like a pretty simple thing to write but with my lack of coding skill it is impossible. Also I'm pretty surprised that I couldn't find no addon that does this, it is a pretty useful function that tbh should be there natively.
Thanks for any suggestions!

"It is a pretty useful function that tbh should be there natively" - tbh, this is a very subjective statement. I have never needed such thing in 25 years doing 3D.

@GordonBrinkmann Well, it's not something that is necessary, but definitely useful to preview how something will look like in the final render, things like bump on a fabric material can often seem like enough in render preview but then not enough on a final render, also same with scale of the texture.
